# Updating contacts in d365 sales with python PATCH Error

Tags: python, dynamics-crm

I've just gotten connected to dynamics API and I'm trying to apply a flag to some contacts from a Excel sheet. I've authenticated correctly but when I send my patch request I get the error:

> {"error":{"code":"","message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."}}

I've also tried PUT which did not work. POST as expected just created a blank record.

This is my code

```
import requests
import json
import csv

# Step 1: Parse the CSV data
csv_file_path = 'test.csv'

with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    contacts = [row[0] for row in reader if row]

# Step 2: Authenticate and obtain an access token
client_id = 'x'
client_secret = 'x'
tenant_id = 'x'
token_endpoint = 'x'

token_payload = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'resource': 'x'  
}

response = requests.post(token_endpoint.format(tenant_id=tenant_id), data=token_payload)
print(response.text)
access_token = json.loads(response.text)['access_token']


# Replace the placeholders with the appropriate API endpoint and request payload
contacts_endpoint = 'https://x.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/contacts'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
    'OData-Version': '4.0'
}

for email in contacts:
    # Create the request payload for updating the contact record
    contact_payload = {
        'description': 'x'  # add flag to description field of contacts
    }

    # Construct the URL for updating the specific contact record
    contact_url = f'{contacts_endpoint}?$filter=emailaddress1 eq \'{email}\''

    # Send the PATCH request to update the contact record
    response = requests.patch(contact_url, headers=headers, json=contact_payload)
    print(response.text)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        print(f"Custom flag applied for contact with email: {email}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to update contact with email: {email}")
```

I'm not entirely sure where I went wrong but any help is appreciated! In the meantime I'm playing with the dynamics365crm python package.

Any other methods or thoughts would be great!

Comment: the problem is with the contact_url you are using to update the record, the one you are sending is not correct (as it is a filter for a GET request). Use my tool Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB to create the update request and if you need the python code export to postman and get the python code from postman

Comment: @GuidoPreite. I appreciate your comment and this tool is very helpful! is there no way to filter contacts via email for a patch request?

Comment: you can add an alternate key based on the email address field, but it will make the contacts unique by that field (so you can't have two contacts with the same email). You can use the email to patch instead of the GUID